# sizeToFit in a custom View

Tags: ios, resize, uilabel, custom-view

I am trying to write a custom view, which is a subclass of a UILabel

I dragged a UILabel to the storyboard, set it to the class of the given view.

I then tried to override draw in rect, only to find out that the label does not adjust its height to what i need.

After some further reading, i overrode the "sizeThatFits:" method with this

```
-(CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size{
    if(!self.bg){
        return [super sizeThatFits:size];
    }
    CGFloat width = self.bg.size.width;
    CGFloat height = self.bg.size.height;
    CGFloat length = [self.text length];
    CGFloat padding = self.paddingBetweenLetter * (length -1);
    size.width = width*(length+padding);
    size.height = size.height;
    return size;

}


-(void)setBg:(UIImage *)bg{
    _bg = bg;
    [self sizeToFit];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];

}
```

however, the height remains the same.

What am i missing ?

Comment: Did you call `sizeToFit` method on the other side? Is the `self.bg` property set? Give us some more information.

Comment: self.bg is a uiimage, and on setBg i called [self sizeToFit], [self setNeedsDisplay]

Comment: Is auto layout turned on?

Comment: yes (this comment is too short but one word is enough for the answer)

Comment: Then make sure you do not have a height constraint. I also do not understand the purpose of `size.height = size.height`.